# Springboot AppRun failed:Error creating bean with name 'configDataContextRefresher'

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm working on a Spring Boot project. I got a weird error when I start AppRun
Below is the error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'xxManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [xxDataSourceConfig.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'refreshEventListener' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/autoconfigure/RefreshAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'refreshEventListener' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configDataContextRefresher' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/autoconfigure/RefreshAutoConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.cloud.context.refresh.ConfigDataContextRefresher] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@3b192d32]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:603)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZBbi.png)

I've checked springboot version and spring cloud version:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
</parent>

<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Hoxton.SR3</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

I can build jar file, but I can not run the service.
Please Help! THanks a lot!

Comment: Please provide the code causing the error.

Comment: I've add info above

Comment: Plz post the repository file